# error CS1061: 'ParticleSystem' does not contain a definition for 'Stop' and no accessible extension

Tags: c#, unity3d

```
public class PrometeoCarController : MonoBehaviour { 

       public ParticleSystem RLWParticleSystem;

       if(RLWParticleSystem != null){
             RLWParticleSystem.Stop();
       }

}
```

В ParticleSystem есть метод Play и Stop. В документации от Unity это сказано.
В другом проекте все эти партиклы работаю исправно. Но стоит мне импортировать сцену из asset store в свой проект, как сразу выдает эту ошибку

При импорте сцены в пустой проект - все хорошо

Пробовал сделать импорт в пустой проект и потом подтянуть файлы с основного проекта. Также начинает выдавать ошибку. Еще начал писать, что происходит импорт asset'ов, но он длится бесконечно

Asset name - Prometeo Car
https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/physics/prometeo-car-controller-209444

Comment: У вас в проекте может быть определен где-то класс `ParticleSystem` с таким же названием. В таком случае его нужно просто переименовать.

Comment: Либо указать пространство имен явно `UnityEngine.ParticleSystem`.

Comment: Блин. Чувствую себя тупым. Я почему-то создал скрипт "ParticleSystem".
Спасибо за помощь. Кинь номер, кину на чай)

Comment: Здесь всё бесплатно. :)